# How do I remove the content of the parent component from the child component in Angular?

Tags: angular, routes, components, parent-child

I have an issue with routes in Angular.

The URLs work fine but my problem is that when I visit the child component i.e., **CreateEventComponent**, the content of the parent component i.e., **EventsComponent** also renders.

How do I **remove** the **content** of the **parent component** **from** that of the **child**?

```js
    const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: '', component: EventsComponent,
        children: [
          { path: 'create', component: CreateEventComponent }
        ]
      }
    ];
```

### Content of the parent component

```html
<p>Events works</p>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

### Content of the child component

```html
<p>Create event works.</p>
```

Comment: so the child component is not really a child component. perhaps need to change the design.

Comment: don't forget to upvote my answer and mark as answer if it helps you

Answer (score 1):

Your code works as it is intended.

If you do not want the parent component to display, then you need to change the design of your application similar to the following.

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: EventsComponent },
  { path: 'create', component: CreateEventComponent }
]
```

When the user visits the relative path `/create`, it will only load the `CreateEventComponent`.

Currently, your application is loading the `EventsComponent` along with the `CreateEventComponent` as a child.